nginx 1.27.0 serves wrong document root for subdomain
Hi guys I'm trying to setup a vhost for a dockerized nextcloud installation. I've got several other vhosts already running on the system, amongst them one hosting a mailcow instance, which is also dockerized (But I guess this is not relevant).
When I try setting up another vhost for nextcloud I get an error message in the browser saying:
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Apache/2.4.61 (Unix) Server at localhost Port 8080.
Is this an exception from the docker-container? Because I find it irritating that this claims to be from apache although I'm running nginx as a reverse proxy, apache2 is not running on my server.
This is my vhost for the nextcloud instance:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name cloud.rheno-palatia.eu;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    http2 on;
    server_name cloud.rheno-palatia.eu;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.rheno-palatia.eu/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.rheno-palatia.eu/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;";

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!SHA1:!kRSA;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 0;
    }
}

If I run docker ps this is what I'm getting:
e9aae6b299a1   nextcloud/all-in-one:latest   "/start.sh"              About an hour ago   Up 53 minutes (healthy)   80/tcp, 8443/tcp, 9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp                                                                                                                                                               nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer

If anyone could tell me what I misconfigured here and have to change to get to my nextcloud instance, I'd appreciate that a lot.
Greetings, derelektrischemoench

The error message is straight forward. Emphasis mine.

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port. Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please. Apache/2.4.61 (Unix) Server at localhost Port 8080.

The Docker image uses Apache to serve Nextcloud. Apache complains that you speak plain HTTP on an SSL-enabled port.
The fix is to stop doing that, and start speaking SSL to it by using https in the NGINX config, or configure Apache (the docker image) not to use SSL on that port.

Is this an exception from the docker-container? Because I find it irritating that this claims to be from apache although I'm running nginx as a reverse proxy, apache2 is not running on my server.

In such cases - Read the error message. Then start researching what it says. It came from Apache, yet you're running nginx, so where does it come from? What does it say is the error? Is it reasonable?
In this case the error message was even in more or less plain English.
